# Нарисовать круг, используя только CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Можно ли нарисовать круг, который будет отображаться в большинстве браузеров (IE, Mozilla, Safari), используя только `CSS`?

Перевод вопроса: [Draw Circle using css alone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936972/draw-circle-using-css-alone)

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/6936972/7394871

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ну раз уж в вопросе сказано *"используя только CSS",* то так и отвечу:

```css
html {
  background: white;
}

body {
  width: 10em; /* поддерживаются любые единицы, в том числе проценты */
  margin: 1em auto;
  background: silver;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

body::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 19):

- Создайте `div` с одинаковым высотой и шириной, образуя тем самым
  квадрат (для круга используйте те же величины).
- Добавьте `border-radius` 50%, что сделает квадрат круглым по форме.
- Затем вы можете поиграть с фоном-цветом / градиентами / (даже с
  псевдоэлементами), чтобы создать что-то вроде этого:

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.sphere {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 500%;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: inset -10px -10px 100px #000, 10px 10px 20px black, inset 0px 0px 10px black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5%;
}
.sphere::after {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  content: '';
  height: 45%;
  width: 12%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4%;
  left: 15%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(40deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="sphere red"></div>
<div class="sphere green"></div>
<div class="sphere blue"></div>
<div class="sphere yellow"></div>
<div class="sphere"></div>
```

Перевод ответа: [Draw Circle using css alone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936972) @jbutler483

Comment: Просили круг а не сферу...

Answer (score 13):

А мне понравился этот [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6937010/4500765), он единственный из всех поддерживает IE8-, поскольку не использует `border-radius`:

Вместо этого вставляется символ круга, с номером unicode `25СF`:

```css
.circle:before {
  content: ' \25CF';
  font-size: 200px;
}
```

```html
<span class="circle"></span>
```

Comment: А мне не понравился этот прием, потому что даже при 200px уже видны зазубрины изображения. Ловите плюс за труды.

Comment: Какие зазубрины? Вектор же. Можно добавить немножко `text-shadow`

Comment: @vp_arth вот не знал, что текст это вектор, спасибо, что просветили.Увеличите масштаб и увидите ступеньки, мне и так видно

Comment: Увеличил font-size до 500px, масштаб в браузере - до 500%. Никаких зазубрин...

Comment: Ну значит надо спросить кого-нибудь третьего :)

Comment: А вот тут напротив - http://i.stack.imgur.com/GIXcB.png

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55527/discussion-between-alexandr-t-and-vp-arth).

Answer (score 7):

Думаю с кодом тут все понятно:

```css
.circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "circle"></div>
```

Comment: конечно с кодом всё понятно - это стандартный код для получения круга свойствами css/  Для поддержки нового пользователя ловите плюс

Answer (score 6):

Вот миксин для создания круга

```
@mixin circle($width, $color) {
      width: $width;
      height: $width;
      background: $color;
      border-radius: $width/2;
    }

.circle {
  @include circle(200px, #123);
}
```

Использование -

```
<div class="circle "></div>
```

Comment: Не могу найти информацию про миксины в стандарте CSS3, не поделитесь ссылкой?

Comment: @andreymal, а их там и нет. По крайней мере, не в этой форме. В стандарте есть `@apply`, который по сути тоже миксин.

Comment: Кстати, с процентами работать не будет.

Comment: Поищите инфу про препроцессоры - sass, scss или stylus, это чудесная штука, там есть переменные, функции, вложенность и еще куча классных штук. Если хотите совсем в тренде быть - заодно и про postcss почитайте. Оно позволяет проанализировать код и указывает на ошибки и проблемы несовместимости.

Answer (score 6):

Ещё есть вариант с использованием кругового градиента:

```css
.circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(black 0%, black 70%, transparent 70%);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

некромантии пост :3

```css
#x{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-top: 250px dotted red;
  width: 400px; /* при меньшей ширине, 250px не влезет из-за пробелов вокруг круга и т.д.
  при таком подходе, вероятнее всего ширину придется подбирать методом тыка, увы */
  text-align: center;
  font: 30px bold;
}

#y{
  display: inline list-item;
  list-style: disc inside; /* if need empty - use "circle" */
  font: 50px bold; /* да, габариты тут какие то... гхм... специфические */
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id='x' title='красная кнопка'>не нажимать!</div>
<div id='y' title='зеленый кнопка'>нажимать!</div>
```

если не брать в расчет треш с багом при `1px dotted`, поддержка ~IE4+

https://webref.ru/css/border-style

https://webref.ru/css/list-style-type

Comment: Ого, классный финт с border'ом!