# Как создать такое?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать такой круг внутри с такими текстами?
Все что приходит в голову в `div` положить 2 текста и дать ему `border-radius : 50 %`, 
вот сделал

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.oval{
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3px;  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="oval">
    <h2>0,5</h2>
    <p>kg</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Именно так как вы написали и надо

Comment: думаете это правильный подход ?

Comment: На самом деле, походов много, но пойдём от противного... Почему считать его "неправильным"? И что у вас конкретно "не получилось"?

Comment: не получилось разделить экран так по полам

Comment: щас выложу код минуточку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.circus{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #1798D8;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: arial;
}

.circus div:nth-child(1){
  font-size: 44px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.circus div:nth-child(2){
  font-size: 26px;
  letter-spacing: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="circus">
  <div>0,5</div>
  <div>кг</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  width: 10em; /* поддерживаются любые единицы, в том числе проценты */
  margin: 1em auto;
  background: silver;
  border-radius: 50%;
```

[Дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/640689/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-css)